# How to insert breakpoints and step through a Gazebo plugin?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugins, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Does anyone know if there's any way to insert breakpoints and step through a Gazebo plugin? This would be very useful to help with debugging logical errors. I've tried inserting breakpoints in the eclipse editor, compiling and running the launch file but it doesn't seem to work. As such, I've just resorted to printf([var])'s for now.

Thanks very much!

Angus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34759/how-to-insert-breakpoints-and-step-through-a-gazebo-plugin?/) by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 438 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been curious myself. Here are two resources that I found on the issue from the gdb world. Hope they're more useful for you than they were for me!

[forum.soft32.com](http://forum.soft32.com/linux/shared-library-GDB-ftopict439956.html)

[inux-mobile-hacker.blogspot.com](http://linux-mobile-hacker.blogspot.com/2008/02/debug-shared-library-with-gdbserver.html)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0